# How to access oracle data using Linq through ADO.net? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, oracle

I am doing this to connect database using sql.

```
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;uid=HR;pwd=fusion;";
    conn.Open();
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("Select * from Students", conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter oraDa = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
    oraDa.Fill(ds, "Students");
    return ds.Tables["Students"];
```

But I want to use Linq instead of SQL. I heard it is possible using Entities.

Answer (score 4):

There are some third party providers that support EF today.  Personally I have been using [Devart dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) for some time.  Datadirect is another such option.

Oracle has a beta version of it's [ODP.Net provider supporting EF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), I haven't tried to use it yet.